# Android Sqlite Database: it couldn't recognize the new column or new table I added in an exsiting database 

Tags: android

I had a working database. I just added one more column in a table. It keeps saying no that column. So I changed the table name. Now it says that no that table name. Then I changed the database name. it still gave error. it works fine after I changed back the table name and remove the extra column I added. Could you please help me figure out what's wrong? 
How do I run my code on a clean emulator? How do I verify that the code that creates the table is getting executed? How do I get the sqlite db off the emualtor and look at it using a sqlite database browser to check that the table does actually exist?

Many thanks!
Tong

Answer (score 2):

For future reference (people googling the problem):

Try the command

```
this.deleteDatabase("database_name");
```

from your main Activity, where "database_name" is your database's name. Do this always if you modify any table structure (adding colums), otherwise you probably will have to use the onUpgrade-method within the SQLLiteOpenHelper.

Also as you said, be sure that you don't have any commas in your db.execSQL(command) at the end of the String command.

Answer (score 1):

In real world, you'll have to change database version and migrate changes in `onUpgrade(..)`.
When developing, you can check "Wipe User Data" in Eclipse's run configuration for you project, then close emulator and launch app again.

Comment: Thank you Alex! I still get the same message. No column names.... Could you please explain how the following code works. I could name my database DBV1 and DBV2. But how the Eclipse reconginze the different versions?  
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS records");
            onCreate(db);
        }

Answer (score 0):

I found the mistake. I missed the comma after I added the last column. Simple mistake could cost a lot.